# Update a colomn in a filtered SharePoint 2010 list using JQuery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

Can sombody help me to do the below using JQuery or other methods:

I'ld like to update the Column3 in a list with a value for all records having Colomn1="value1" and Column2="value2".

Actually, I'll filter the list in SharePoint 2010 using Colomn1="value1" and Column2="value2", and then click on a button that will update the Column3 of all filtered lines with a value.

Comment: your question is not specific to SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

This code will change the value of the a column in the HTML table that SharePoint 2010 used to display a list view. The name of which is ms-listviewtable. The first row is the header, and the rest of the rows contain the list's data.

In this example, each() is over DOM Table Row Elements and Cells represents DOM TD elements. I change the value of the third column.

```
$(".ms-listviewtable tr:not(:first-child)").each(function (index, value ){
value.cells[3].innerText='new value';
 })
```

Hope this is what you had in mind.